# error when i run flutter doctor --android-license

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

Good day Guys, i'm new on flutter & I wan set up flutter and the android SDK(without using android studio) on my device but when i run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`  command i get this error after running the command

```
(/home/olaneat/android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
detailed instructions.
```

this is how i configured my path

```
ANDROID_HOME="$PATH:/home/olaneat/android/Sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:/home/olaneat/android/Sdk/platform-tools"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:SPATH"
```

and i have my SDK already installed
can anyone help out?

Comment: Make sure to set the SDK path on IDE

Comment: i have set the path already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update cmdline-tools direcotry

Try changing the path name *cmdline-tools/tools* to *cmdline-tools/latest*. I was facing the same problem and found that the  directory patern has been updated.

Comment: tnks it worrked